# Ubuntu 20: Define Shift+AltGr as compose key for other keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, compose-key

On Ubuntu 20.04 (but encountered this on 18.04 as well)

I'm trying to get the default compose key (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>) to work on a different keyboard layout. I'm regularly switching between UK (default) and Swiss French layouts, and I like the default <kbd>Compose</kbd> key (with Tweaks I know I can choose other keys, like <kbd>PrintScr</kbd>, <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>, etc., but all these mean abandoning the respective key).

I tried on the terminal, without success, something like the following:

```bash
setxkbmap -option "lv3:ralt_switch_multikey" # also tried "compose:ralt_switch_multikey"
```

Does anybody know how to set <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd> (<kbd>RightAlt</kbd> still works on its own, <kbd>Compose</kbd> only when used with <kbd>Shift</kbd>) even when shifting to other layouts?